# How to merge video and drawing overlay in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am recording a video with AVFoundation framework and want to edit it after capture,I am able to draw shapes on it but how can I merge video and drawing together so that when user play it it will show drawing also.Please help.
Thanks